# In Das Boot, what is Leutnant Werner's role?

Tags: plot-explanation, das-boot

I am re-watching the "Das Boot" (U96) movie, and for the first time I realise that the writings in Leutnant Werner's notebook are in English.
This is shown at two occasions.

[image]

Officially,

Leutnant Werner is some kind of "embedded journalist". **But should
this particular scene give a hint that he actually is a spy for
England?**

Comment: It would be very dumb of him to do that if that was the case. Realistically, this is probably just Petersen trying to appeal to an international audience. It might even have been switched specifically for the English release.

Comment: It would seem almost impossible for a spy on a submarine to send out messages while the ship is on a mission, and if they could inform the enemy of where the sub is it would be likely to get the sub sunk and the spy killed.

Comment: While I think Mr Wilson is perfectly correct your question is still fantastic as a result of your wonderful observation-which version of the film was this still taken from? I was lucky enough to hold off on watching that film for 37 years, having only been 2 in 1981 and growing up with the dubbed VHS as the only home video release accessible, the resulting privilege being that I saw the entire miniseries(with English subs)on a friends DVD before any of the feature length cuts.Having only the directors cut on BD for my many subsequent viewings I have not seen the full length version since..

Comment: Sorry for being an idiot - it clearly states that its from the theatrical cut....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the German version of the film, the diary entries are in German:

[image: diary]

So this scene was either filmed twice, once for the original and once for the International version, or the text was changed in post.

Note that the former was not uncommon at the time. For example, the manuscript scene in Kubrick's Shining has [an English](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lQ_MjU4QHw) and [a German](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GqaMNPtye_M) version as well.
These days, such changes are usually done in post-production, as that is considered cheaper than shooting the same scene twice.

The reason for this, as [pointed out in the comments](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/102071/in-das-boot-what-is-leutnant-werners-role/102447#comment174754_102071), is to give the movie a better chance of selling on the International market.